# Are there any Discussion Forums on Microsoft's Health Care Initiatives?

Tags: healthvault

I am new to Microsoft health care system, like Amalga/Health Vault, and I want to know if any developer here working on Amalga/Health Vault could recommend me some specific forum/mail list/web site for developer community of Amalga/Health Vault, which could exchange more points for Amalga/Health Vault?

Comment: Please edit your title to reflect the actual question you have.

Comment: Thanks TokenMacGuy! Done. :-)

Comment: How is this not programming related? He's asking about forums for Developers using these technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one right now. See [HealthVault Developer Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/healthvault/threads).

Comment: Thanks John, question answered.

Comment: FYI, this link is dead.  There is [one current HealthVault forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/healthvault/threads), but it's not very lively.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the Delay...

Here you have all* the information you can find available on the web.

http://www.microsoft.com/amalga/library/default.mspx#blogs

*at list all I could find

Comment: Thanks! But seems what you recommend is not a discussion forum. Any discussion forum specific for Microsoft health care? :-)

Comment: It search a lot for one of it. Even at the MVP Discussion List (Microsoft) I propose for one, but at this moment I can't find one.

Comment: Sorry, Randolf-RF. Maybe I have not made myself understood. I am looking for discussion forum, but what you suggested is not a discussion forum.